# Android - Get the visible area of a view?

Tags: java, android, layout

Suppose I have an Android `View` that is being partially masked by another `View`.  For instance, imagine that the masking view has a transparent rectangular "window" in the center of it, and my view is centered beneath the window and possessing dimensions that are larger than the dimensions of the window.  In such a case, some rectangular portion of the view will be visible, with the rest being obscured by the mask.

So my question is, is there any straightforward way to retrive the position and dimensions of the visible area *without* having any access to the masking view itself (so without knowing how big the mask's "window" itself is)?

I tried calling `getLocalVisibleRect()`, which sounded promising, but that only seems to return the view's layout rectangle and *not* the rectangle that is actually visible.

Comment: got any solution for this? having the same question..

Comment: Seems duplicate (but without answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724179/how-to-find-whether-an-android-view-is-obscured-by-any-other-view

Comment: ever figured this out?

Comment: Negative.  And so long ago now that I can't even remember _why_ I needed to figure this out.

Comment: @aroth i want to use this, in my scenario my view is getting hidden by keyboard and i am not using `adjustresize` so keyboard is overlapping the View and i want only the visible area.

Answer (score 12):

This is pretty late to the game, but I suspect that `getGlobalVisibleRect` does what you want.

EDIT

For more information, visit this website:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getGlobalVisibleRect(android.graphics.Rect)

I suspect in Kotlin, you can use it like this:

public boolean getGlobalVisibleRect (Rect r,
Point globalOffset)

Replace r with the actual coordinates of the non-clipped area of the view, in the coordinate space of the view's root view,
Hope this helps!

Comment: It works for the simple cases only, when the view wasn't rotated.

Comment: Late reply, but getGlobalVisibleRect only seems to calculate visible portion if the view is restricted (cut off) by one of its parents. Not if another view is overlaying it in something like a relativelayout. In that case, getGlobalVisibleRect gives the rect of the whole view, not just the portion that's uncovered by the masking view

Answer (score 6):

I have used `getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame` method to determine if view is partially visible or not to determine if a soft keyboard is open. You can try it out.

```
Rect r = new Rect();
// r will be populated with the coordinates of     your view
// that area still visible.
rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this not work: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingRect(android.graphics.Rect)

The documentation says that it does what you want.

Comment: Nope, it gives the same result as just calling `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` (i.e. the total view size).  As the documentation says, `getDrawingRect()` "fills in the output rectangle with the values from `getScrollX()`, `getScrollY()`, `getWidth()`, and `getHeight()`".  The `scrollX` and `scrollY` values will be 0 in this case, because there is no scrolling going on.