# How to check if TextView is within the Visible Screen Android

Tags: android, textview

I wanted to know if my textview is within the visible screen region or not..

I have looked at links as:
[Android - Get the visible area of a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073677/android-get-the-visible-area-of-a-view)
[Android: how to check if a View inside of ScrollView is visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628800/android-how-to-check-if-a-view-inside-of-scrollview-is-visible)

But nothing seems to work for me.

Code that i used to check is

```
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    //textview intialized in onCreate as text1
    text1.getHitRect(rect);
    text1.measure(0, 0); 
    //layout is the parent layout (linear) in which i am adding the text view
    Rect acctualView = new Rect(Math.round(layout.getX()), Math.round(layout.getY()), 
            Math.round(layout.getX() + layout.getWidth()), Math.round(layout.getY()         +layout.getHeight()));

    if(Rect.intersects(acctualView, rect))
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "visible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Not visible ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Every width and height of textview and layout is giving me 0 "zero",

Please let me know how to fix this and know whether a view is inside the visible region or not

Here is my complete activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6;
private Context context;
private LinearLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = getLayoutInflater().getContext();
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
    setTextViews();
    checkViewAndUpdate();

}

private void checkViewAndUpdate() {

    Rect rect = new Rect();
    layout.getHitRect(rect);
    if (text1.getLocalVisibleRect(rect)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "visible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Not visible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

private void setTextViews() {

    text1 = new TextView(context);
    text2 = new TextView(context);
    text3 = new TextView(context);
    text4 = new TextView(context);
    text5 = new TextView(context);
    text6 = new TextView(context);

    text1.setText("text1");
    text2.setText("text2");
    text3.setText("text3");
    text4.setText("text4");
    text5.setText("text5");
    text6.setText("text6");

    text1.setTextSize(30);
    text2.setTextSize(30);
    text3.setTextSize(30);
    text4.setTextSize(30);
    text5.setTextSize(30);
    text6.setTextSize(30);

    //layout.removeAllViews();

    layout.addView(text1);
    layout.addView(text2);
    layout.addView(text3);
    layout.addView(text4);
    layout.addView(text5);
    layout.addView(text6);

}
```

}

and my layout only contains LinearLayout (empty)

Comment: your link seems to work. where/when do u trying to call `getXXXVisibleRect()`? if u do it at `onCreate`, it cannot works.

Comment: @ytRino I have added my complete code, please let me know how to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as i wrote on comment, checking visible rect at `onCreate` won't work.
Try this code at end of `onCreate` (instead of call `checkAndUpdate() directly`).

```
 layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                checkViewAndUpdate();
            }
        });
```

View layout does not finish though if you added view at `onCreate`. yes, this time user cannot see the actual activity and view's actual size are not set.
`onGlobalLayout` will call when view layout is ended (and activity is visible).
 at that timing, we can now get size and position of them!

FYI, you can remove this listener by calling `layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)` in `onGlobalLayout()`

Comment: Thanks man , it Works but idk why, some explanation will be awesome.

Comment: @wizyashas added info. hope it will helps.

Answer (score 2):

try with this:

```
if (yourView.getParent().getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    // visible
} else{
    // hiden
}
```

Or this:

```
Rect rect = new Rect();
parentView.getHitRect(rect);
if (imageView.getLocalVisibleRect(rect)) {
    // imageView is within the visible window
} else {
    // imageView is not within the visible window
}
```

Comment: I don't get it , textview.getParent().getVisibility is unavialable

Comment: please, post your xml file

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `for` method?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
 TextView tv = new   TextView(context);
 tv.setTextSize(30);
 layout.addView(tv);
 //Maybe set some listeners...
}
```