# How to find whether an Android View is obscured by any other View

Tags: android, user-interface, view

I want to check whether a particular view (e.g. TextView) is obscured by any other view (e.g. Navigation drawer but not necessarily ).

I see, View::GetVisibilty(), View::IsShown() returns true even if view is obscured by other view/layout